# Realm: Querying and Indexing with One-to-Many relationship

Tags: database, indexing, realm

Lets consider the default Realm example of Person and Dog.

Person with name 'A' has 3 Dogs with respective names - 'X', 'Y', 'Z'

Person with name 'B' has 2 Dogs with respective names - 'X', 'Z'

So the code will be

```
[realm beginWriteTransaction];

Person *personA = [Person createInRealm:realm withObject:@{@"name": @"A"}];
Person *personB = [Person createInRealm:realm withObject:@{@"name": @"B"}];

[Dog createInRealm:realm withObject:@{@"name": @"X", @"owners": @[personA, personB]}];
[Dog createInRealm:realm withObject:@{@"name": @"Y", @"owners": @[personA]}];
[Dog createInRealm:realm withObject:@{@"name": @"Z", @"owners": @[personA, personB]}];

[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

Now, in order to get all the dogs based on owners we write

```
RLMArray *dogs = [Dog objectsWhere:@"ANY owners = %@", personA];
```

or

```
RLMArray *dogs = [Dog objectsWhere:@"ANY owners = %@", personB];
```

How should we set index in this case to improve performance?

How can we inverse link so that we can do

```
RLMArray *persons = [Person objectsWhere:@"ANY dogs = %@", dogX];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not supported yet.

For now you can change the direction of your relationship and have a property of type `RLMArray<Dog>` on `Person`, if you need to traverse it more often in that direction. Alternatively you can maintain two relationships in both direction, you would need to sync them yourself.

We track adding support for that by issue [#1324](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1324).